# Why are my AceGen results not matching with the commercial FE software?

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I conducted a linear FE analysis of a 3D cantilever beam using AceGen/Acefem and Ansys. I find that results are a little bit off from the ansys results. For e.g., the deflection reported at the loading point by Acegen is -0.120862, while Ansys reports a value of -0.12531.

What is the source of this discrepancy? Am I doing something wrong with my Acegen code? Please find the problem description and the codes below.

**Cantilever:**

L x T x W = 60 x 2 x 30;

E = 200;

nu = 0.3 ;

F = -1
@(60,1,30)

**AceGen code:**

```
<< AceGen`
SMSInitialize["3D", "Environment" -> "AceFEM"];
SMSTemplate["SMSTopology" -> "H1", "SMSSymmetricTangent" -> True, 
  "SMSDomainDataNames" -> {"Em - Young's Modulus", 
    "\[Nu] -Poisson's ratio"}, "SMSDefaultData" -> {200, 0.3}];
ElementDefinitions[] := (
  nnodes = SMSNoNodes;
  ndim = SMSNoDimensions;
  nDOF = SMSNoDOFGlobal;
  {Em, \[Nu]} \[RightTee] 
   SMSReal[Table[es$$["Data", i], {i, Length[SMSDomainDataNames]}]];
  Xi \[RightTee] 
   Table[SMSReal[nd$$[i, "X", j]], {i, nnodes}, {j, ndim}];
  Ui \[RightTee] 
   Table[SMSReal[nd$$[i, "at", j]], {i, nnodes}, {j, ndim}];
  pe \[DoubleRightTee] Flatten[Ui];
  
  \[CapitalXi] = {\[Xi], \[Eta], \[Zeta]} \[RightTee] 
    Table[SMSReal[es$$["IntPoints", i, Ig]], {i, 3}];
  \[CapitalXi]n = {{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 
     1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}};
  NI \[DoubleRightTee] 
   Table[1/8 (1 + \[Xi] \[CapitalXi]n[[i, 
         1]]) (1 + \[Eta] \[CapitalXi]n[[i, 
         2]]) (1 + \[Zeta] \[CapitalXi]n[[i, 3]]), {i, 1, 8}];
  X \[RightTee] SMSFreeze[NI . Xi];
  u \[RightTee] SMSFreeze[NI . Ui];
  Je \[DoubleRightTee] SMSD[X, \[CapitalXi]];
  Jed \[DoubleRightTee] Det[Je];
  H \[DoubleRightTee] 
   SMSD[u, X, "Dependency" -> {\[CapitalXi], X, SMSInverse[Je]}];
  SMSFreeze[\[Epsilon], 1/2 (H + Transpose[H]), "Symmetric" -> True];
  {\[Lambda], \[Mu]} \[DoubleRightTee] SMSHookeToLame[Em, \[Nu]];
  \[Psi] \[DoubleRightTee]  ((\[Lambda]/
        2) (\[Epsilon][[1, 1]] + \[Epsilon][[2, 2]] + \[Epsilon][[3, 
          3]])^2) + \[Mu] (TensorContract[
       TensorProduct[\[Epsilon], \[Epsilon]], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]);
  )
SMSStandardModule["Tangent and residual"];

SMSDo[Ig, 1, SMSInteger[es$$["id", "NoIntPoints"]]];
ElementDefinitions[];

wgp \[RightTee] SMSReal[es$$["IntPoints", 4, Ig]];
SMSDo[m, 1, nDOF];
Rgm \[DoubleRightTee] Jed SMSD[\[Psi], pe, m];
SMSExport[ wgp Rgm, p$$[m], "AddIn" -> True];
    SMSDo[n, m, nDOF];
        K \[DoubleRightTee] SMSD[Rgm, pe, n];
        SMSExport[wgp K, s$$[m, n], "AddIn" -> True];
    SMSEndDo[];
SMSEndDo[];
                                                
SMSEndDo[];

SMSStandardModule["Postprocessing"];

SMSDo [Ig, 1, SMSInteger [es$$ ["id", "NoIntPoints"]]];
ElementDefinitions [];

\[Sigma] \[DoubleRightTee] 
  SMSD[\[Psi], \[Epsilon], "Symmetric" -> True];
SMSGPostNames = {"DispX", "DispY", "DispZ", "StressX", "StressY", 
   "StressXY", "StrainX", "StrainY"};
SMSExport[{u[[1]], u[[2]], 
   u[[3]], \[Sigma][[1, 1]], \[Sigma][[2, 2]], \[Sigma][[1, 
    2]], \[Epsilon][[1, 1]], \[Epsilon][[2, 2]]}, gpost$$[Ig, #1] &];
SMSEndDo[];


SMSWrite[];
```

**AceFEM code:**

````
<< AceFEM`;
SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain["cube", "3D", {"Em *" -> 200, "\[Nu] *" -> 0.3}];
SMTMesh["cube", 
  "H1", {60, 2, 
   30}, {{{{0, 0, 0}, {60, 0, 0}}, {{0, 2, 0}, {60, 2, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, 
      30}, {60, 0, 30}}, {{0, 2, 30}, {60, 2, 30}}}}];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 30}, {0, 0, 30}}], 1 -> 0, 
  2 -> 0, 3 -> 0];
SMTAddNaturalBoundary[Point[{60, 1, 30}], 3 -> -1];
SMTAnalysis[];
SMTShowMesh["BoundaryConditions" -> True]
SMTNextStep["\[Lambda]" -> 1];
SMTNewtonIteration[];


SMTShowMesh["Field" -> "DispX"]

SMTPostData["DispX", Point[{60, 1, 30}]]
SMTPostData["DispY", Point[{60, 1, 30}]]
SMTPostData["DispZ", Point[{60, 1, 30}]]
```
````

Comment: Do you use the same mesh and the same type of finite elements for both simulations?

Comment: @Henrik. Yes. I do.

Comment: I always find point loads confusing, as they do not exist. Which makes your model veri idealized. Why don't you use a pressure instead?

Comment: Yes, you are right.....distributed loads are more closer to the ansys results

Answer (score 4):

I compared your element to AceShare's and your element returns same results thus its correct. Have you checked also uniaxial load case in ANSYS? AceFEM yields analytical solution in that case. For results to match exactly you have to make sure that everyting is identical. No of integration points per element (Default in AceGen is 8 for H1), same interpolation functions, same gradient, no additional internal modes etc. AceFEM only consideres your element contributions and loads and solves this, while ANSYS can do some additional manipulations (e.g. Weak springs), so if you can switch everything off and you have to solve assuming its linear tangent. You can also try constraining only middle axes in Y/Z and everything in X, then influence of clamped base will be negligible.

Eventually, unless you have an ideal case, where values at element levels are homogenous, you will never obtain exact solution and you can only get closer with better methods, finer mesh etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.....I maintained the same parameters in both the simulations. Anyway, I find that the distributed loads give closer results to ansys compared to point loads

Answer (score 2):

You did the wrong postprocessing. Displacements are nodal quantities, not the Gauss point quantities. There is no need to evaluate displacements at the Gauss points and then project them to the nodes as it is done in FEM for stresses.
Look in the help or AceShare for examples of how the postprocessing of nodal quantities should be done correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Even if I fetch the nodal values, I get the same result. For e.g., SMTPostData["DispZ", Point[{60, 1, 30}]] and SMTNodeData[Point[{60, 1, 30}], "at"] give the same results. I also get the same result when I use SMTPostData["w", Point[{60, 1, 30}]] for the Aceshare element "ML:SED3H1DFLEH1DHooke". Hope my approach is right